# Not able to get pagepeel effect

Tags: javascript, html, animation

Hey guys am trying to get pagepeel effect using an image and jquery

here is the js fiddle for it

[pagePeel jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XvSX/)

Problem am having is that am not able to get the pagepeel effect properly.
    below is the creative view of it in html

```
      var page_peel_container=pagePeel.create('div',{'id':'page_peel_container'});
      var page_peel=pagePeel.create('div',{'id':'page_peel'},  {'width':'87px','height':'87px','position':'absolute','right':'0px','top':'0px','overflow':'hidden'});
      page_peel_container.appendChild(page_peel);
      var page_peel_img=pagePeel.create('img',
        {'id':'page_peel_img','width':'195','height':'195','border':'0','src':'http://www.laylagrayce.com/images/swatches/JY/grey_linen_sm.jpg'},
    {'position':'absolute',
     'height':'195px',
     'width':'195px',
          'zIndex':'9001',
          'top':'4px',
          'right':'25px',
           'webkitTransform':'rotate(45deg)',
           'transform':'rotate(45deg)',
           'msTransform':'rotate(45deg)',
             'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod=\'auto expand\')' 
 });
```

am rotating  the image since i should be able to click on the iframe . otherwise the image comes on top of it. 
Please check the jsfiddle link and let me know how i cn get the pagepeel effect properly